# C++ Minecraft2D Block Type?

Tags: c++, enums

I was working on a Minecraft2D kind of game in Java and I decided to create the same game in C++ to enhance my C++ abilities. But I have a problem. I had a BlockType enum in Java which contained that BlockType's image location and hardness (how long it takes to mine it). I figured out that in C++ enums are different than the ones in Java. How can I implement this in C++?

BlockType.java:

```
public enum BlockType {
    STONE("res/blocks/stone.png",3),
    COAL("res/blocks/coal.png", 2),
    AIR("res/blocks/air.png",0),
    GRASS("res/blocks/grass.png",1),
    DIRT("res/blocks/dirt.png",1),
    DIAMOND("res/blocks/diamond.png",5),
    REDSTONE("res/blocks/redstone.png",3),
    COBBLE("res/blocks/cobble.png",3),
    BRICK("res/blocks/brick.png",4),
    IRON("res/blocks/iron.png",4),
    GOLD("res/blocks/gold.png",5);
    public final String location;
    public final int hardness;
    BlockType(String location, int hardness){
    this.location = location;
    this.hardness = hardness;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go with something similar to SingerOfTheFall answer:

```
enum blocks
{
    STONE,
    COAL,
    GOLD
};

struct BlockType {
    BlockType(std::string loc, int h): location(loc), hardness(h) {}
    std::string location;
    int hardness;
};

BlockType blockTypes[] = {
  BlockType("res/blocks/stone.png", 3), // STONE
  BlockType("res/blocks/coal.png", 2), // COAL
  BlockType("res/blocks/gold.png", 5) // GOLD
};

// use:
cout << "Location: " << blockTypes[STONE].location << endl;
```

`std::map` is a good container, but it uses binary search every time you need to get the value. Indices will be from 0 to n so you can use array instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will be using this one. But here's another question if you don't mind: How can I use this with multiple files? I mean how should I declare the struct or enum? In the header file? I'm sorry, I'm a noob in C++ so I'll be very happy if you answer me.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), keyed by an `enum` value and with a value of [`std::pair<sd::string, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair):

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

enum BlockType
{
    STONE,
    COAL,
    GOLD
};

std::map<BlockType, std::pair<std::string, int>> BlockTypes;

BlockTypes[STONE] = std::make_pair(std::string("res/blocks/stone.png"), 3);
BlockTypes[COAL]  = std::make_pair(std::string("res/blocks/coal.png"),  2);
BlockTypes[GOLD]  = std::make_pair(std::string("res/blocks/gold.png"),  5);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ enums work another way indeed.

```
enum eMyEnum
{
    ONE = 15,
    TWO = 22
};
```

is about all you can get from them, basically they just allow you to create 'names' for INT values.

For your case, I would make an enum for the block names:

```
enum blocks
{
    STONE,
    SAND,
    <...>
};
```

and then make a map:

```
< blocks, pair< string, int > >
    ^       ^     ^      ^
    |       |     |      |
    |       |     |     hardness
    |       |    path to picture
    |       |      
    |      the block's attributes: the picture path and hardness
    |
  the block type from the enum (e.g. SAND)
```

Or just make a structure to hold three values:

```
struct block
{
    string type;//or int, or your enum type, depending on how do you want to store it.
    string picture;
    int hardness;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use and `std::map` whan an array will do? (Which can be initialized at compile time)

```
using namespace std;

struct BlockType {
    enum {
       STONE = 0,
       COAL,
       LAST
    };
    BlockType(string location, int hardness) : location(location), hardness(hardness) {}
    const string location;
    const int hardness;
    static const BlockType Blocks[LAST];
};

const BlockType BlockType::Blocks[] = {
    BlockType("res/blocks/stone.png", 3),
    BlockType("res/blocks/coal.png", 2)
};

int main() {
    cout << BlockType::Blocks[BlockType::STONE].location << `\n`;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine both the answers here and make a mapping of `enum` to block `struct`

```
struct Block
{
  block(path, str) : strength(str), path(path) {}
  int str;
  std::string path;
};

enum BlockType
{
  STONE,
  COAL,
  ETC
}

std::map<BlockType, Block> blocks;
blocks[STONE] = Block("c:/block/bla.png", 1);
blocks[STONE].str; // 1
blocks[STONE].path; // "c:/block/bla.png"
```